# Multiple cases returning unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql

This query returns
154 rows

```
SELECT s_campaign_id,  COUNT(b_entry_type_tag)::decimal * 1 AS tags,(COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1 AS redirects,COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv)::decimal * 100 / NULLIF((COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1,0) AS crp,SUM(f_revenue) * 1000 / NULLIF((COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1,0) AS rrm,COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv) AS conversions,SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date BETWEEN '2021-01-31' AND '2021-01-31'THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue,SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date BETWEEN'2021-01-30'AND'2021-01-30'THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue2 FROM tbl_reports WHERE (d_gen_date>='2021-01-31' AND d_gen_date<='2021-01-31') GROUP BY s_campaign_id
```

while this

```
SELECT s_campaign_id,  COUNT(b_entry_type_tag)::decimal * 1 AS tags,(COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1 AS redirects,COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv)::decimal * 100 / NULLIF((COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1,0) AS crp,SUM(f_revenue) * 1000 / NULLIF((COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1,0) AS rrm,COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv) AS conversions,SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date BETWEEN '2021-01-31' AND '2021-01-31'THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue,SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date BETWEEN'2021-01-30'AND'2021-01-30'THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue2 FROM tbl_reports WHERE ((d_gen_date>='2021-01-30'AND d_gen_date<='2021-01-30')OR(d_gen_date>='2021-01-31' AND d_gen_date<='2021-01-31')) GROUP BY s_campaign_id
```

returns 206 rows.
I dont understand why

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL, but this is not valid MySQL code.

Comment: Is the only difference the WHERE clause?  The second one asks for 2 days (in a clunky way).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT d_gen_date,  COUNT(b_entry_type_tag)::decimal * 1 AS tags,
       (COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1 AS redirects,
       COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv)::decimal * 100 / NULLIF((COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1,0) AS crp,
       SUM(f_revenue) * 1000 / NULLIF((COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1,0) AS rrm,
       COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv) AS conversions,
       SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date BETWEEN '2021-01-31' AND '2021-01-31'THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date BETWEEN'2021-01-30'AND'2021-01-30'THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue2
FROM tbl_reports
WHERE (d_gen_date >= '2021-01-30'AND d_gen_date <= '2021-01-30') OR
      (d_gen_date >= '2021-01-31' AND d_gen_date <= '2021-01-31')
GROUP BY d_gen_date
ORDER BY d_gen_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: any other way to do it without order by and limit 1? because d_gen_date is dynamic and change to other column

Comment: @cgvfgf34 . . . I'm not sure what your comment means.  This answers the question you have asked here -- and `d_gen_date`  looks like a column in this query.